# How to display double byte session string correctly in java web app?

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, utf-8, session-variables

in controller:

```
 String something="测试文字";
 session.setAttribute("something", something);
```

in jsp:

```
 ...
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
 ...
 汉语<br/>
 ${something}
```

result in web page:

```
 汉语
 ä¸­å›
```

Type double byte directly on the page, it displays well.
The session attribute/variable with double byte value from controller that cannot be displayed well. The variable is not from request/post, so can not solve it by modifying server.xml connector part. please advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the jsp compile java code? You will see how the ${something} variable is used. It will help to explain the result.

Comment: Try `String something="\u6d4b\u8bd5\u6587\u5b57";`